# Firebase ambiguous reference "FIRMessagingAPNSTokenType... is ambiguous"

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

After upgrading the Firebase Pods the project have ambiguous reference problems, any suggestions?

when I use the Pods with Version 4.10.0 it works perfectly, but if I use the latest version (5.0.0) I get the error.

My Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AppName' do
    pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.10.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '4.10.0'
    pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger'
    pod 'AppCenter'
end

target 'AppName DEV' do
    pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.10.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '4.10.0'
    pod 'GoogleToolboxForMac/Logger'
    pod 'AppCenter'
end`
```

[image]

Thaks and advance!!

Comment: Can you please post your complete error as text instead of an image? Unfortunatly I forgot my magnefying glass in the train so I can't read it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem writing...

```
[FIRMessaging messaging].APNSToken = deviceToken;
```

instead...

[image]

On didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you have the same class in 2 different frameworks. Can it be that you reference both 4 and 5 at the same time?

Try to comment out "BRy-Autenticador DEV" section and build only the 'BRy-Autenticador' target.

Check your Podfile.lock after running "pod install". It should contain only one version of Firebase frameworks.

Comment: Hello thanks for helping me so far, regarding using versions 4 and 5 at the same time I think it does not happen because I do a cleaning before installing the PODS see:
'rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods; rm -rf Pods; rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*; pod deintegrate; pod setup; pod update; pod install;'
With regard to the compilation directives I need the 2 because I have files that are present in one and not the other, but I will perform the test to isolate this possibility

I'll post the result soon.

Thank you